# CKeditor undo redo Events

Tags: ckeditor

Need Ck editor events before it performs undo and redo operations? I have tried the undo manager events after Redo and after Undo but it gives events after operation is performed and I need it before that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `beforeCommandExec` event and check for the `undo` and `redo` events. Something like this where `editorInstance` is and CKEDITOR instance.

```
editorInstance.on('beforeCommandExec', function(e){
    if(e.data.name === 'undo') {
        // handle before undo
    }
    if(e.data.name === 'redo') {
        // handle before redo 
    }
});
```